# Login user to my website in Chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, google-chrome-app

I have users registered to my website that connected their Google+ account, and I'd like to auto login them from a packaged Chrome app.

I'm following [1] and the related example [2].

I can successfully perform a Google account authentication and obtain a token and user info.
Next, I'd like to "exchange" Google token for a "my website" token.

I was thinking to:

1. app sends to server the token and user_id
2. server requests https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me and verifies that user_id and token match
3. server searches for the user corresponding to (google) user_id and logs he in

The alternative would be to implement an oauth login form and follow Non-Google account authentication in [1], but it seems too much extra work to me.

Any suggestion / alternative way?

[1] http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity.html
[2] https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/identity

Answer (score 1):

[edit: as pointed out in comments, not a secure method.]

Use the [identity api](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity.html) to make a request from the app to get the google+ id:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
(with the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me oath scope)
```

In the response you will find

```
{
 "kind": "plus#person",
  ...
 "id": "117022097663427079142",
```

Send that ID to your server to look up the associated ID that your system uses.

You do not need to (and should not) send the bearer token.

Comment: I don't think this solution is secure. Anyone can spoof any Google id. I've actually simplified my solution just sending the token (no user_id, it can be get server side).